# How to enabled CRM Analytics Dashboard Component in App Builder?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, embedded, crm-analytics

I am working on Embedded App and I have built it successfully. Now I want setup this in customer org but I am unable to get through this.

How do I enable the CRM Analytics Dashboard in App Builder?
[image]

this is what I am seeing in customer org,

[image]

Comment: Do you have permission 'CRM Analytics Growth permission set license with Use CRM Analytics permission' enabled ?

Comment: Check if your user has permission set 'Administrador Plus of CRM Analytics'

Comment: Hello, I'm guessing it's correct that the "Analytics View Only User" (AnalyticsViewOnlyUser licence) alone will not work for a View Only access to a dashboard shared through this? I've found on testing that it does work for the "Engagement History" component but does not for the "CRM Analytics Dashboard" component. Should these component act differently?  Thanks